# How to use 2 foreach loops in a checkbox array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some trouble when it comes to updating checkboxes.

I have two different tables with arrays and i am trying to compare data from both tables as they contain similar info.

The ref no is used as the the unique identifier since the information is CSV uploaded therefore i cant use the primary key.

As for the query i ran it on php admin and it showed the results were fine and i am aware the code is vulnerable to SQL injection but if i can find a solution to get i could work on it.

**Structure of both tables:**
[image: Structure of both tables]

I run the following code

```
<?php
include 'DBConfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    reconcile();
}

function reconcile(){
include 'DBConfig.php'; 

if(isset($_POST['reconciled']) && (isset($_POST['reconciled2']))){  


    foreach ($_POST['reconciled']as $recon1){

    foreach($_POST['reconciled2'] as $recon2){
        $query="select bankstatement.date,bankstatement.referenceno,bankstatement.debit,bankstatement.credit,bankstatement.status,cashbook.date,cashbook.referenceno,
        cashbook.debit,cashbook.credit,cashbook.status
            from   bankstatement cross join cashbook
        where '$recon1' = '$recon2' and cashbook.credit = bankstatement.debit and cashbook.debit = bankstatement.credit and cashbook.date = bankstatement.date and bankstatement.status = '0' and cashbook.status = '0'";
        $result= mysqli_query($db,$query);

    if($result)
    {
    $recon1 = implode(',' ,$_POST['reconciled']);
    $recon2 = implode(',' ,$_POST['reconciled2']);


    echo $change = "update bankstatement set status='1' where statementid=$recon1";
    echo $change1 = "update cashbook set status='1' where cashbookid=$recon2";


    $db->query($change);
    $db->query($change1);

    echo "<script>
        alert('Success in Reconciling Process!!!');
        window.location.href='viewreconcile.php';
        </script>
        ";


    }else{
        echo "<script>
        alert('Error in Reconciling Process!!!');
        window.location.href='managereconcile.php';
        </script>
        ";
    }
}
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Results after code is run:**
[image: Results after code is run]

My issue now comes when trying to compare the data from both tables. The image of results show the first ref no's that were stored in the database after import instead of searching the similar ref no's. I dont get an error message instead i'm shown a success message though no update actually happens and no hanging occurs.

[A sample of the CSV test data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyqZB.png)

Comment: What IS your issue? Please describe the result of your current code. Do you receive an error message? Does it hang? Also, it would be halpful to see the CSV test data you use.

Comment: If you copied that code ... `include 'DBConfig.php;` is missing a closing `'` and this should show you an error

Comment: echo out your `$change` and `$change1` and see if they have correct mysql syntax. If `$recon1` is `imploded` your `where statementid=$recon1` will probably fail. Also there's [mysqli_error](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to show you possible mysql errors

Comment: @kerbholz thanks for the help i've echoed $change and $change1 and see that updating is a problem but how do sort the issue of  imploding $recon because without it it shows me the error: Array to string conversion

Comment: Have you tried Igor Ilic's answer ?!

Comment: Yes ive tried but it takes me to the next page will the success message though no update actually happens

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to update the data of multiple rows with the same value you can't send it as `where cashbookid=$recon2` but instead your code should look like this:

```
echo $change = "update bankstatement set status='1' where statementid IN($recon1)";
echo $change1 = "update cashbook set status='1' where cashbookid IN ($recon2)";
```

Since your values are being sent as a comma separated values, this will look for all those rows and update them.

Comment: Tried your solution and it worked fine however it tends to update more values i $change1 than in $change, what could be the issue?